# "Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, gradle

Please I am finding issues running my app after making changes to these files by adding firebase dependencies. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

My app was working initially however after adding the firebase dependencies to the Gradle build I am getting a **Build failed Exception**. I have read many solutions provided on Stackoverflow however they aren't solving my problem. Please find my code below

```
\\I am facing an error running my application and please find both build gradles code listed below
\\This is my build gradle in my main project

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
\\This is my build gradle in my app

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.tchow"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

```
\\Error Message

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:.
     Required by:
         project : app
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add BoM:

```
dependencies {
// Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')

// Declare the dependency for the Analytics library
// When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

}

Comment: I just cleared my errors by ensuring my  I used this dependency
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'